# CreateDC() fails with lasterror 2

Tags: windows, winapi, printing, gdi

I have implemented a class that gets local printers and, depending on the application option,  uses one of the local printer available.

Firstly, the class enumerates the printers (EnumPrinters - PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL) and saves the corresponding PRINTER_INFO_2. Then, it gets printer capabilities (DeviceCapabilites) and DEVMODE. Each class instance will access one printer.

When application selects the printing option, it selects which printer will be used and its corresponding instance of the class. Then, this instance creates the device context:

```
    m_hdc = CreateDC (m_pi2->pDriverName, m_pi2->pPrinterName, NULL, m_pdm));
```

where

```
    HDC m_hdc;
    PRINTER_INFO_2 * m_pi2;
    DEVMODE * m_pdm;
```

and process all printing data accordingly.

The problem is that sometimes, the CreateDC return NULL and GetLastError() return ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(2).

I mean 'sometimes' because in other machines, with same printer, same processor, same Windows XP SP3 image and same test data, the CreateDC processes correctly. In addition, the reinstalling the system and application the problem disappears sometimes no.

I am looking forward to hearing any suggestion that helps me to find out the issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my experience, GetLastError() does not return reliable information from the CreateDC() (or most of the GDI functions, for that matter).  I wouldn't put too much stock in the error actually being 2.

Comment: @HansPassant: Why would updating a printer driver fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem loading a file required by the printer driver.  You could use Process Monitor (a free SysInternals tool downloadable from microsoft.com) to get a bunch of information about what's going on at the time of the error.  I'd do a capture and look at failed file and registry accesses.  The fact that it fails intermittently on one particular machine seems consistent with a messed up driver configuration.

Another thing you could try is to create an information context rather than a device context.  You can't print with an IC, but you can query information about the device, which may be a way to get additional information.

Comment: I'm extremely skeptical that a missing file causes this, but simple enough to test.  Open any application (notepad will do) and print something.  If it prints, the driver is fine and the problem is in the OP's code.